# comparing 2 textview values

Tags: android, textview

i have 2 TextView

Textview1 Value "0", Textview2 Value "0.05"

---

trying this codes

```
  private TextView geting_id_one, geting_id_two;



    {onCreate)
    geting_id_one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textview1);
    geting_id_two= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textview2);
```

---

```
    (button Click)
   float  one = geting_id_one.getText().toString();
   float  two = geting_id_two.getText().toString();

        if (one>two){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"TextView1 Bigger than TextView2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (one>two){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"TextView2 Bigger than TextView1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

error viewing

> E/Error In Thread: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.05"

Comment: That is because you are parsing the float value into "parseInt" that is why you are getting NumberFormat Expection.

Comment: The exception is thrown because the string value cannot be converted to Integer. Instead use parseDouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0.05` is not valid `Integer` value

You should use `double` or `float` instead of `int`

Sample Code

```
// inside oncreate()
geting_id_one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textview1);
geting_id_two= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textview2);



// inside  button Click
double one = Double.parseDouble(geting_id_one.getText().toString());
double two =  Double.parseDouble(geting_id_two.getText().toString());

// OR

float one = Float.parseFloat(geting_id_one.getText().toString());
float two =  Float.parseFloat(geting_id_two.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare the string value of two textviews by comparing their string value like:

```
    if (text1.getText().toString().equals(text2.getText().toString())) {
            //both are equal
    } else {
           //both have different value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to parse `float` values with `Integer.parseInt()` method. Use `Double.parseDouble("your_number_string")` or `Float.parseFloat("your_number_string")` instead. You can cast it into `integer` if you want.